# Sigma Change of Variable

Tags: summation, geometric-series

For the problem

> Simplify the following as much as possible without using a calculator.
> $\sum_{r=-7}^{n} ({\frac{7}{n})^r}, n>0$

I have tried using the geometric sum formula by splitting the summation into two pieces

$\sum_{r=-7}^{0} ({\frac{7}{n})^r}$ + $\sum_{r=1}^{n} ({\frac{7}{n})^r}$

Then by using the formula for geometric series

$\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$

I came up with the answer:

$\frac{1-(\frac{n}{7})^7}{1-\frac{n}{7}} + \frac{1-(\frac{7}{n})^n}{1-\frac{7}{n}} - 1$

However, the answer does not seem to be right when I check it. Can anyone help me or guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write it as $ \sum\limits_{s=0}^{n+7} (\frac 7 n)^{s-7}$ (where $s=r+7$)  which is $(\frac 7  n)^{-7} \sum\limits_{s=0}^{n+7} (\frac 7 n)^{s}$. Now write down the geometric sum.

You should get $\frac {n^{n+8}-7^{n+8}} {(n-7) 7^{7}n^{n}}$

Comment: If you have time, could you show me how you went from the formula to the geometric sum? r = (7/n) and n+7 are confusing me

Comment: I am changing the variable $r$ to  a new variable $s=r+7$. As $r$ ranges from $-7$ to $n$ this new variable $s$ ranges from $0$ to $n+7$. @KennyCheng

Comment: @KennyCheng Note that the geometric sum in my answer is of the type $ \sum\limits_{s=0}^{n+7}x^{s}$ where the common ration is $x=\frac 7 n$. Do not use $r$ for the common ratio. That will confuse you.

Comment: After simplification, I got $\frac {n^{n+8}-n7^{n+8}} {(n-7) 7^{7}n^{n}}$. The extra n in the numerator beside 7 is from when I put the denominator under a common denominator and multiplied the n to the numerator. My simplification is wrong however and I agree with your simplification, but for some reason, I cannot reach your simplification? Is my algebra wrong somewhere?

Comment: @KennyCheng Please check again. My answer is correct. The $n$ and $n^{7}$ in the numerator should cancel out with $n^{8}$ in the denominator.